# Multiple SQL Server statements do not work on same form

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am working on a C# project with a Microsoft SQL Server database.

This is how I have connected the database:

```
DataSet ds_display = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter da_display = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Files", "Data Source=DESKTOP-21EVLOU\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=UPM;Integrated Security=True");
da_display.Fill(ds_display, "Files");

dataGridView1.DataSource = ds_display.Tables["Files"].DefaultView;
```

The code works fine for all operations including reading data, writing data, updating data and deleting data as well. However, it works only when each operation is on individual form, not on a single form.

I have created several different panels and show/hide them based on the respective button. Each panel has its own operation and Data Grid View. The display option works fine but the addition, updating and deleting operations do nothing.

Can you please help identify the issue here?

Comment: Is it possible that you're reusing the same `SqlDataAdapter da_display` variable for the multiple queries? They'd need to be seperate variables.

Comment: That's a very general question. You need to do some debugging to more spcifically define the issue. It could be connecting to a different db. It could be silently gobbled by an error handler. You may be updating the wrong key.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I am using separate SqlDataAdapter variables for each adapter. Moreover, the scope of each SqlDataAdapter is within the Click function.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid How do I specifically identify the underlying issue? The display query runs fine on all the buttons of the form. However, the other queries (update, delete, write) do not work at all. They even do not throw any error. It is like the statement isn't executed at all.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the actual line of code. Things may become clearer. Either the code isn’t run or isn’t what you expect.